Kotlin flow.Flattenmerge does not seem to work
I have a StateFlow which should change if one of three flows produces a new value:
class FlowViewmodel:ViewModel(){

    val currentWeek =MutableStateFlow<String>("start week")
    val _overlayRequested:MutableStateFlow<String> = MutableStateFlow("")

    val _overlayChanged:MutableStateFlow<ScheduleLoadingState> =
         MutableStateFlow(ScheduleLoadingState.Loading)

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    val weekSchedule:StateFlow<ScheduleLoadingState> = flowOf(
        currentWeek.flatMapLatest { week->getWeekSchedule(week) },
        _overlayRequested.flatMapLatest { scheduleOwner->
            if(scheduleOwner !=""){
                requestOverlaySchedule(scheduleOwner)
            }else{
                flowOf()
            }
        },
        _overlayChanged
        )
        .flattenMerge()
        .stateIn(scope=viewModelScope,SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), initialValue = ScheduleLoadingState.Loading)


    private fun getWeekSchedule(week: String)= flow<ScheduleLoadingState> {
        val oldLoadingState:ScheduleLoadingState = weekSchedule.value
        emit(ScheduleLoadingState.Loading)
        emit(
            try {
                //if there is an oldPackage update all schedules for requested week
                if (oldLoadingState is ScheduleLoadingState.Success) {
                    val returnedResult =
                        RequestResult.Success(
                            SchedulePackage(
                                "skeleton for $week",
                                "schedule for $week",
                                oldLoadingState.schedulePackage.overlaySchedules)
                        )
                    if (returnedResult is RequestResult.Success) {
                        ScheduleLoadingState.Success(returnedResult.data)
                    } else {
                        ScheduleLoadingState.Error(
                            (returnedResult as RequestResult.Failure).error
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    //else get new package with just the schedule of the user
                    val newPackage = RequestResult.Success(
                        SchedulePackage("skeleton for $week","schedule for $week")
                    )
                    if (newPackage is RequestResult.Success) {
                        ScheduleLoadingState.Success(newPackage.data)
                    } else {
                        ScheduleLoadingState.Error(
                            (newPackage as RequestResult.Failure).error
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            //as exceptions are caught this can go but keep it to be on the safe side
            catch (e: Exception) {
                ScheduleLoadingState.Error("error in getWeekSchedule")
            }
        )
    }

    private fun requestOverlaySchedule(scheduleOwner: String)=flow<ScheduleLoadingState> {
        val weekScheduleState = weekSchedule.value
        when (weekScheduleState) {
            is ScheduleLoadingState.Success -> {
                emit(ScheduleLoadingState.Loading)
                weekScheduleState.schedulePackage.overlaySchedules.add(scheduleOwner)
                val newPackage = RequestResult.Success(
                    weekScheduleState.schedulePackage
                )
                if (newPackage is RequestResult.Success<SchedulePackage>) {
                    emit(ScheduleLoadingState.Success(newPackage.data))
                } else {
                    emit(ScheduleLoadingState.Error(
                        (newPackage as RequestResult.Failure).error)
                    )
                }
            }
            is ScheduleLoadingState.Loading -> {}
            is ScheduleLoadingState.Error -> {}
        }
    }

    fun requestOverlay(scheduleOwner: String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _overlayRequested.emit(scheduleOwner)
        }
    }

    fun removeOverlay(overlayId: Int){
        val scheduleState = weekSchedule.value
        if ( scheduleState is ScheduleLoadingState.Success){
           scheduleState.schedulePackage.overlaySchedules.removeAt(overlayId)
           _overlayChanged.update{
               ScheduleLoadingState.Success(scheduleState.schedulePackage)
           }
        }
    }
}

Neccesary classess
data class SchedulePackage(
    val skeleton:String,
    val schedule: String,
    val overlaySchedules:MutableList<String> = mutableListOf(),
){
    var overlayToShow:Int = -1
    var message:String = ""

    val maximumOverlaysReached:Boolean
        get() = overlaySchedules.size == 4

    fun addOverlay(overlaySchedule:String){
        overlaySchedules.add(overlaySchedule)
    }
}
sealed class ScheduleLoadingState {
    object Loading:ScheduleLoadingState()
    data class Error(val error:String):ScheduleLoadingState()
    data class Success(val schedulePackage:SchedulePackage):ScheduleLoadingState()
}

and neccesary dependencies
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    def kotlin_coroutines_version = "1.7.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
//lifecycle components
    def lifecycle_version = "2.4.1"
    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
// Annotation processor
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:truth:1.5.0"
    testImplementation "app.cash.turbine:turbine:1.0.0"

When I test adding the overlay everything works fine. A new schedule is produced from requestOverlaySchedule and a new state is emitted by weekSchedule.
Next I added a removal of the overlay to my test. Now when I collect the value for the weekSchedule flow, the test times out with no value produced in 3s app.cash.turbine.TurbineAssertionError: No value produced in 3s
I collected _overlayChanges in my test to see if it does change its value. I confirmed it by removing the private modifier and collecting it in my test. I use app.cash.turbine for this. The test is like this:
class FlowViewmodelTest {

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(StandardTestDispatcher())
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun testFlattenMerge(){
        runTest{
            turbineScope {
                val viewModelUnderTest = FlowViewmodel()
                val currentWeekFlow = viewModelUnderTest.currentWeek.testIn(backgroundScope)
                val overlayRequestedFlow = viewModelUnderTest._overlayRequested.testIn(backgroundScope)
                val overlayChangedFlow = viewModelUnderTest._overlayChanged.testIn(backgroundScope)
                //the next one is the combined flow
                val weekScheduleFlow = viewModelUnderTest.weekSchedule.testIn(backgroundScope)
                advanceUntilIdle()

                //assert that all base flows are initilized
                val firstvalue1 = currentWeekFlow.awaitItem()
                val firstvalue2 = overlayRequestedFlow.awaitItem()
                val firstvalue3 = overlayChangedFlow.awaitItem()
                assertThat(firstvalue1).isEqualTo("start week")
                assertThat(firstvalue2).isEqualTo("")
                assertThat(firstvalue3).isEqualTo(ScheduleLoadingState.Loading)
                //weekschedule cycles through Loading and then succes withj schedule of start week
                val firstCombinedValue = weekScheduleFlow.awaitItem()
                val secondCombinedValue = weekScheduleFlow.awaitItem()
                assertThat(firstCombinedValue).isEqualTo(ScheduleLoadingState.Loading)
                assertThat(secondCombinedValue).isInstanceOf(ScheduleLoadingState.Success::class.java)
                assertThat((secondCombinedValue as ScheduleLoadingState.Success).schedulePackage.schedule).isEqualTo("schedule for start week")
                weekScheduleFlow.expectNoEvents()

                viewModelUnderTest.requestOverlay("request overlay for kli")
                advanceUntilIdle()
                currentWeekFlow.expectNoEvents()
                overlayChangedFlow.expectNoEvents()
                val secondFlow2Value = overlayRequestedFlow.awaitItem()
                assertThat(secondFlow2Value).isEqualTo("request overlay for kli")
                val fourthCombinedValue = weekScheduleFlow.awaitItem()
                val fourthACombinedValue = weekScheduleFlow.awaitItem()
                assertThat(fourthCombinedValue).isEqualTo(ScheduleLoadingState.Loading)
                assertThat(fourthACombinedValue).isInstanceOf(ScheduleLoadingState.Success::class.java)
                assertThat((fourthACombinedValue as ScheduleLoadingState.Success).schedulePackage.schedule).isEqualTo("schedule for start week")
                val schedulePackage = (fourthACombinedValue as ScheduleLoadingState.Success).schedulePackage
                assertThat(schedulePackage.overlaySchedules).isNotEmpty()
                assertThat(schedulePackage.overlaySchedules.size).isEqualTo(1)
                assertThat(schedulePackage.overlaySchedules.first()).isEqualTo("request overlay for kli")

                viewModelUnderTest.removeOverlay(0)
                advanceUntilIdle()
                val secondFlow3Value = overlayChangedFlow.awaitItem()
                currentWeekFlow.expectNoEvents()
                overlayRequestedFlow.expectNoEvents()

                assertThat(secondFlow3Value).isInstanceOf(ScheduleLoadingState.Success::class.java)
                assertThat((secondFlow3Value as ScheduleLoadingState.Success).schedulePackage.overlaySchedules).isEmpty()

                val sixCombinedValues = weekScheduleFlow.awaitItem() //This one produces no data in 3s
                weekScheduleFlow.expectNoEvents()
                assertThat(sixCombinedValues).isEqualTo(secondFlow3Value)
            }
        }
    }
}

So my question is, why does weekSchedule not react to _overlayChanged emitting a new value? It is my understanding that flattenMerge 'emits' a new value when one of the composing flows emits a value.
I also tried to use merge(flow1, flow2, flow3), which should have the same effect. It also does not work.

Can you provide a minimal working example? Something that can be executed?

I tried but the code is rather complex. I added the removeOverlay function, which just changes something in the package and then updates the _overlayChange state with a new ScheduleLoadingState.

Also made a analoguous model which some simple MutuableStateflows. That one works as expected.

Sorry, there is just too much missing. The only thing I can comment on is the following: 1.) You should definitely prefer merge over the flowOf().flattenMerge approach. 2.) You should be careful to switch to an empty flow in _overlayRequested.flatMapLatest. That won't provide any value. Should probably be OK with merge, but you could try, just for testing purposes, to use a flow with a value instead. -- For anything else your example really needs to be executable. It's a good idea to provide a Test, but when it cannot be executed, its pretty much useless.

If you cannot provide a better example, I'm afraid this question will be unanswerable.

I did some changes and now this should be a working example. I replaced some classes with strings and cut out the dependecies for usecase, repositories etc. This still throws the 'no value produced in 3s' error.

The problem is that you expect the flow weekSchedule to offer the same (as in equal) Success object a second time. The flow is, however, a StateFlow, and that means that successive updates with the same value will be omitted. From the documentation:

Values in state flow are conflated using Any.equals comparison in a similar way to distinctUntilChanged operator.

After all, a StateFlow represents a single value, and when that value is still the same nothing should change.
Now, you might think that the value did change: After all, you removed an element from the list. Let's have a look at what the flow contains after viewModelUnderTest.requestOverlay was called:
Success(schedulePackage=SchedulePackage(
    skeleton=skeleton for start week,
    schedule=schedule for start week,
    overlaySchedules=[request overlay for kli],
))

And this is how it looks after viewModelUnderTest.removeOverlay is called:
Success(schedulePackage=SchedulePackage(
    skeleton=skeleton for start week,
    schedule=schedule for start week,
    overlaySchedules=[],
))

Clearly, overlaySchedules is now empty where it contained a value before. But what you see here is just a string representation. overlaySchedules is actually still the same object in both cases: A MutableList<String>. Only the content of the list has changed, not the list itself. And although you create a new Success object with
ScheduleLoadingState.Success(scheduleState.schedulePackage)

its content is still the same SchedulePackage object with the same MutableList. When the StateFlow now compares the both values with equals it finds they have the same properties and assumes the value didn't change. It won't emit a new value and the following line in your test will never get a new value until it times out after 3 seconds:
val sixCombinedValues = weekScheduleFlow.awaitItem()

So much for why that happened. Now, what can be done to fix this?
The simple solution would be to just make the MutableList an immutable list:
data class SchedulePackage(
    val skeleton: String,
    val schedule: String,
    val overlaySchedules: List<String> = emptyList(),
)

Now, you obviously won't be able to add or remove items from an immutable list, so you need to create a new one each time it changes. But that's the point: We want to have a new object so that it won't register as equal anymore:
val newPackage = RequestResult.Success(
    weekScheduleState.schedulePackage.copy(
        overlaySchedules = weekScheduleState.schedulePackage.overlaySchedules + scheduleOwner
    )
)

_overlayChanged.update {
    ScheduleLoadingState.Success(
        scheduleState.schedulePackage.copy(
            overlaySchedules = scheduleState.schedulePackage.overlaySchedules.let {
                it - it[overlayId]
            }
        )
    )
}

This will solve your problem, the test should now pass.
However, the way your flows are intertwined makes their logic hard to understand and hard to maintain: You experienced first hand how opaque the flows have become, why you have posted your question in the first place. You also have already experienced how hard it is to change something: It took you several attempts and probably a considerable amount of time to create the example.
From what I have learned of your code so far is that it probably could be drastically simplified. The key is to have a clear hierarchy of which flow depends on which and use combine when you need another flow's value to create a new value. And remember: Always use immutable objects as state.
I would strongly recommend you clean that up as soon as possible. This will certainly come back some time later to bite you if left unattended.
If you want someone to verify your refactoring, feel free to use the sister site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get a second opinion. You can use your the same user as here to post there. The site works the same as Stack Overflow except that they only focus on code that already works as intended. They do not provide bug fixes, they provide a code review with pointers on how your code could be improved.

Thank you for reviewing and providing a solution. I do know mutuableStateFlow needs a new value and thought I provided it by creating a new instance of ScheduleLoadingState. But I did not realize that by it being a data class the properties decide the uniqueness and not the reference.
